vscodium — How to make vim registers persistent across restarts?
When using VSCode with extension vscodevim v1.17.1, vim registers are persistent across restarts of VSCode.  When opening VSCode, I can just paste the stored values from previous sessions.
However, when using VSCodium with the same extension v1.29.0, vim registers are wiped when the application is closed.  New sessions start with empty registers.
Is there a way to make the vim emulation extension to behave the same in VSCodium as it does in VSCode, and save the contents of registers on close for future sessions?
